# How to convert String to map in groovy?

Tags: groovy

content of log

```
name:ram,sam,joe
age:21:22:45
hight:6,5.9,5.11
```

this log collect to string blow cm
String cm = //content log//
output came [name:ram,sam,joe age:21:22:45 hight:6,5.9,5.11]
need to convert as a Map
Then if we call any key from map need to print values of key.

Comment: Please show us the code you tried so that we can help you.

Comment: How is quoting being handled? E.g. what happens of a key or value
contains a `:` char? Since this already looks very close to the
`.toString()` from a groovy map, please double check, that no one
gives you this by accident.  `map.toString()` is an **unsuitable**
serialization format.  Better use JSON or something like that.

Comment: Log message
1.1:1.1.1,2.2,3.3                                                             
2.5:2.5.5,22.11,25.11                                                                                                             
3.0:2.1,22

string commentMsg = Logmessage.getbody
output came like this
[1.1:1.1.1,2.2,3.3 2.5:2.5.5,22.11,25.11 3.0:2.1,22]

from here need to collect in to map 
if i call key ex- map.get(1.1)
1.1.1,2.2,3.3

again i need to send which ever key value call collect as a List